# Coredata execute Group By sqlite query - iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

SELECT count(Name),Name from Test group by Name.

How to execute this query using Coredata - iOS SDK

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13285273/730701).

Answer (score 1):

you don't.

Core Data is not a database.  It is an object hierarchy that happens to persist to disk and one of those persistence choices is a database.

NSPredicate will allow you to retrieve entities from Core Data and you can then use KVC to group them as needed and perform counts.

Comment: Marcus, I see you haven't been online in a week, which is bad timing for me because I have a bizarre and irksome core data issue. Should you get a chance to take a look, it's described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18049831/unwanted-objects-appearing-in-core-data-relationship Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved with NSExpression

```
    // count messages
    let countExpression = NSExpression(format: "count:(message)")
    let countED = NSExpressionDescription()
    countED.expression = countExpression
    countED.name = "messages"
    countED.expressionResultType = .Integer32AttributeType

    // request
    var request = NSFetchRequest()
    request.entity = entityDescription
    request.propertiesToFetch = ["username",messageED]
    request.propertiesToGroupBy = ["username"]
```

it is important to set the return to dictionary

```
    request.resultType = .DictionaryResultType
```